# Can I run an application for a certain version of Ubuntu in a virtual machine with different Ubuntu version?

Tags: versions

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 in my Windows machine using the MV workstation player.  Now I need to install the OpenMS proteomic software in my Linux virtual machine.  There are 2 Open MS versions for Linux:

- Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus)

  - Ubuntu Universe amd64
  - openms_2.0.0-4build3_all.deb
  - package for LC/MS data management and analysis
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

  - Ubuntu Universe amd64
  - openms_1.11.1-3_all.deb
  - package for LC/MS data management and analysis

In other words, there is not an Ubuntu 17.10 version.  Could I install either version of the software in the Ubuntu 17.10 virtual machine?

Comment: you will probably run into dependency problems with the version for 14.04 because of newer libraries, but you can try the one for 17.04. Note: 17.10 uses wayland by default not Xorg if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you. What are wayland and Xorg and what is the dfference?

Comment: X11/X.org and Wayland are graphics protocols that make the GUI desktop possible.  Some years back, developers decided that creating a new protocol from the ground up is better than continually adding on to the 30 year old X11 protocol. Since the core protocol is different, GUI programs need to be written to run in Wayland. Also for security reasons,  some features available in X.org are not present in Wayland.

Comment: I have some R programs (pipeline) that call Open MS and for which I am going to do a GUI using RStudio server so that we can host the pipeline in a web server to make the pipeline public.  The programs were previously written in windows by I an moving everything to Linux.  Can I still work on the GUI for the R programs using RStuido server?  RStudio server only works in Linux, there is not PC version.

Comment: The question comes down, I think, to whether  Ubuntu 17.04 uses Wayland or X.org.  If Ubuntu 17.04 uses Wayland a graphical application that runs in Ubuntu 17.04 will also run in Ubuntu 17.10.  Would there be a problem if Ubuntu 17.04 runs on X.org and I install an application that has been developed for Ubuntu 17.04 in Ubuntu 17.10? Does it only matter if the ubuntu 17.04 application needs a graphic display and not if the application just runs some processes but does not require a graphical display.

Comment: if it does not run a graphical display the the question of xorg vs wayland does not apply. 17.04 used xorg as default (I believe) but wayland was an optional install. Likewise, 17.10 has xorg as an optional install. On the login screen, click Sessions to see if "Ubuntu on Xorg" is present.